# The function callable by command get calling twice

Tags: wpf, f#, gjallarhorn

One of the smaller projects required functional changes...so I decided to update version of the Gjallarhorn.Bindable.Wpf library also.

In fact, I just added an additional parameter where it was needed.

But now the application doesn't work correctly because the function callable by command gets calling twice.

The minimal example is below:

```
type Message = |Number of int

let rand = Random()
let mbindings _ source _ = 
    let getNumber() = 
        let number = rand.Next() 
        printfn "RAND = %A" number //print a number twice
        number |> Some
    [
        Bind.Explicit.createCommand "NewNumber" source
        |> Observable.map (fun _ -> getNumber())
        |> Observable.toMessage Number
    ]

let mcomponent : IComponent<int, obj, Message> = 
    Component.fromExplicit mbindings

let app nav = 
    let model = 42
    let update message _ =
        match message with
        |Number number -> number
    Framework.application model update mcomponent nav
```

...

```
let nav = Navigation.singleView Application MainWin
let app = app nav.Navigate
Framework.RunApplication (nav, app)
```

**Is it a bug on the library or I miss something?**

Comment: It's possible it's a bug. Any chance you could put up a github repo and link to an issue? https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/issues

Comment: Also - is it printing 2x every time you click on the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [a bug](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/issues/9). It has been corrected in [Gjallarhorn.Bindable Beta 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gjallarhorn.Bindable/1.0.0-beta6).

The issue was that the framework subscribed to the observable in the binding twice. This is typically fine, but in your case, the observable has a side effect, which was getting run multiple times. I reworked how this is handled in the framework to prevent multiple subscriptions, so it should no longer fire twice if you upgrade to the latest.